# open another teaching bubble on click of heading in Teaching bubble

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react

First Teaching bubble as per your example

```
        import * as React from 'react';
        import  { MouseEvent } from 'react';

        import { DefaultButton, IButtonProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
        import { ITravelBriefProps } from './ITravelBriefProps';
        import { TeachingBubble } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TeachingBubble';
        import { useBoolean } from '@uifabric/react-hooks'; 
        import styles from './TravelBrief.module.scss';
        import {TeachingBubbleBasicNext} from './Teaching copy'
        import {
          getTheme,
          mergeStyleSets, 
          FontWeights,
          ContextualMenu,
          Toggle,
          //DefaultButton,
          Modal,
          IDragOptions,
          IconButton,
          IIconProps,ITeachingBubbleProps, shouldWrapFocus
        } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
        import { readyException } from 'jquery';
        //import { TeachingBubbleBasicNext } from './Teaching copy';
        const iconButtonStyles = {
          alignItems: 'normal',
          root: {
            color: '#dd1d21',
            marginLeft: 'auto',
            marginTop: '2px',
            marginRight: '2px',
            
            
          },
          rootHovered: {
            color: '#dd1d21',
          },
        };

        const ArrowIcon: IIconProps = {  iconName: 'OfficeChat' };




        const examplePrimaryButtonProps: IButtonProps = {
          
          children: 'Yes',
          onClick: function () {
            window.open("")
        }

        }



        const constheadline :ITeachingBubbleProps={

         headline:""

        }

        export const TeachingBubbleBasicExample: React.FunctionComponent <{country:any,rating:any}>= (country,rating)=> {
          const [teachingBubbleVisible, { toggle: toggleTeachingBubbleVisible }] = useBoolean(false);

          const [teachingBubbleVisibleNext, { toggle: toggleteachingBubbleVisibleNext }] = useBoolean(false);

          
          const examplePrimaryButtonProps: IButtonProps = React.useMemo(
            () => ({
              
              children: 'Show 2nd buble!',      
              onClick: toggleteachingBubbleVisibleNext,
            }),
            [toggleteachingBubbleVisibleNext],
          );  
          
          
                
          const exampleSecondaryButtonProps: IButtonProps = React.useMemo(
            () => ({
              children: 'Maybe later',
              onClick: toggleTeachingBubbleVisible,
            }),
            [toggleTeachingBubbleVisible],
          );

          return (
            <div>
              <IconButton
                    styles={iconButtonStyles}
                    iconProps={ArrowIcon}
                    //ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
                    onClick={toggleTeachingBubbleVisible}
                    id="targetButton"/>
                    <label className={styles.label} >PREPARATIONS</label> 
                    

              {teachingBubbleVisible && (
                <TeachingBubble
                  target="#targetButton"
                  //primaryButtonProps={examplePrimaryButtonProps}
                  //secondaryButtonProps={exampleSecondaryButtonProps}
                  onDismiss={toggleTeachingBubbleVisible}
                  //headline="Discover what’s trending around you"
                >
                     <ul>
              <li className={styles.label}><a href="#"  onClick={toggleteachingBubbleVisibleNext} >Clickhere</a>.  </li>
          
                </TeachingBubble>
              )}
              
              {teachingBubbleVisibleNext && (
                <TeachingBubble
                  target="#targetButtonNext"          
                  onDismiss={toggleteachingBubbleVisibleNext}
                  styles={iconButtonStyles}
                >
         <ul>
               <li className={styles.label}>Second Teaching bubble </li>
              
         </ul>        </TeachingBubble>
              )}
            </div>
          );
        };
```

Second Teaching bubble in another location code  which i want to open from First one

```
        import * as React from 'react';
        import { DefaultButton, IButtonProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
        import { ITravelBriefProps } from './ITravelBriefProps';
        import { TeachingBubble } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TeachingBubble';
        import { useBoolean } from '@uifabric/react-hooks';
        import styles from './TravelBrief.module.scss';
        import {
          getTheme,
          mergeStyleSets, 
          FontWeights,
          ContextualMenu,
          Toggle,
          //DefaultButton,
          Modal,
          IDragOptions,
          IconButton,
          IIconProps,ITeachingBubbleProps
        } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
        import { PropertyPaneSlider } from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
        const iconButtonStyles = {
          alignItems: 'normal',
          root: {
            color: '#dd1d21',
            marginLeft: 'auto',
            marginTop: '2px',
            marginRight: '2px',
            
            
          },
          rootHovered: {
            color: '#dd1d21',
          },
        };

        const ArrowIcon: IIconProps = {  iconName: 'OfficeChat' };

        interface ModernProps {
          pdata: number;
          }
        const examplePrimaryButtonProps: IButtonProps = {
          
          children: 'Yes',
          onClick: function () {
            location.href = "" 
        }
        }

        export const TeachingBubbleBasicNext: React.FunctionComponent <{country:any,rating:any}>= (country,rating)=> {
          const [teachingBubbleVisibleNext, { toggle: toggleteachingBubbleVisibleNext }] = useBoolean(false);
          

          const exampleSecondaryButtonProps: IButtonProps = React.useMemo(
            () => ({
              children: 'Maybe later',
              onClick: toggleteachingBubbleVisibleNext,
              test:""
              
            }),
            [toggleteachingBubbleVisibleNext],
               
          );
           return (
            <div className={styles.TeachingbubblePositing}>
              <div> <IconButton
                    styles={iconButtonStyles}
                    iconProps={ArrowIcon}
                    ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
                    onClick={toggleteachingBubbleVisibleNext}
                    id="targetButtonNext"
                text={teachingBubbleVisibleNext ? 'Hide TeachingBubble' : 'Show TeachingBubble'}
                  />  <label className={styles.label} >COUNTRY RISK RATING</label> 
        </div>
              {teachingBubbleVisibleNext && (
                        <TeachingBubble
                          target="#targetButtonNext"          
                          onDismiss={toggleteachingBubbleVisibleNext}
                          styles={iconButtonStyles}
                        >
                 <ul>
                       <li className={styles.label}>Second Teaching bubble </li>

                 </ul>        </TeachingBubble>
                      )}

            </div>
          );      
            
        };
```

both Target target="#targetButtonNext"

Comment: can anyone please help on this?

Comment: There is one another functionality of multi-step bubbles. Please see last example provided here. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/examples/teachingbubble?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest It may help.

Answer (score 2):

@kumar,

I copied the [example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/examples/teachingbubble?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest) in codepen and did some changes as below:

```
const { DefaultButton, IButtonProps, TeachingBubble, Fabric, initializeIcons } = window.FluentUIReact;
const { useBoolean } = window.FabricReactHooks;

// Initialize icons in case this example uses them
initializeIcons();

const TeachingBubbleBasicExample: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [teachingBubbleVisible, { toggle: toggleTeachingBubbleVisible }] = useBoolean(false);
  
  const [SecteachingBubbleVisible, { toggle: SectoggleTeachingBubbleVisible }] = useBoolean(false);
  
  const examplePrimaryButtonProps: IButtonProps = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      
      children: 'Show 2nd buble!',      
      onClick: SectoggleTeachingBubbleVisible,
    }),
    [SectoggleTeachingBubbleVisible],
  );     
        
  const exampleSecondaryButtonProps: IButtonProps = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      children: 'Maybe later',
      onClick: toggleTeachingBubbleVisible,
    }),
    [toggleTeachingBubbleVisible],
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <DefaultButton
        id="targetButton"
        onClick={toggleTeachingBubbleVisible}
        text={teachingBubbleVisible ? 'Hide TeachingBubble' : 'Show TeachingBubble'}
      />

      {teachingBubbleVisible && (
        <TeachingBubble
          target="#targetButton"
          primaryButtonProps={examplePrimaryButtonProps}
          secondaryButtonProps={exampleSecondaryButtonProps}
          onDismiss={toggleTeachingBubbleVisible}
          headline="Discover what’s trending around you"
        >
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, nulla, ipsum? Molestiae quis aliquam magni
          harum non?
        </TeachingBubble>
      )}
      
      {SecteachingBubbleVisible && (
        <TeachingBubble
          target=".ms-TeachingBubble-primaryButton"          
          onDismiss={SectoggleTeachingBubbleVisible}
          headline="This is my Second techingbubble"
        >
          some text goes here !
        </TeachingBubble>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const TeachingBubbleBasicExampleWrapper = () => <Fabric><TeachingBubbleBasicExample /></Fabric>;
ReactDOM.render(<TeachingBubbleBasicExampleWrapper />, document.getElementById('content'))
```

It could open the second TeachingBubble:

[image]

BR

Comment: Thanks is there possibility to open this teaching bubble in another place not just adjacent

Comment: i tried giving similar in my code to open on another location but on click it come and disappear , however if i give similar it open in adjacent

Comment: Use the [target](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/react-internal/iteachingbubbleprops?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest#target) property to set the location to open the techingbubble

Comment: tried giving target property but it comes and go in fraction of second

Comment: Is it possible to share your project code? via github or other methods?

Comment: Update code in question please check this code i am working target="#targetButtonNext" keeping to open it from first teaching bubble but it comes and go

Comment: any luck with code..